# Reflection API + Annotations: how to send class-inheritor as parameter?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have annotation & want to send class name there as parameter:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
public @interface PostApiRequest {

    Class<?> value();
}
```

I attach annotation to method of parent class:

```
@PostApiRequest(value = ...)
@Override
public ResponseEntity<D> save(@RequestBody D dto) {
```

Application don't know, which inheritor shall call this method, than I want to send inheritor there to work with its properties later. I should see any like this:

```
@PostApiRequest(value = this.class)    //send inheritor
@Override
public ResponseEntity<D> save(@RequestBody D dto) {
```

but it not works.

Please, give advice, how to do it?

Comment: neither `this.class` nor `this.getClass()` should work because the expression must be constant

Comment: What's the intent behind creating the annotation?

Comment: this annotation log API requests for controllers. for this, I need inheritor's properties, like @RequestMapping value & so on.